# Best way to disabled DIV onClick in React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a component with a div that accepts onClick and aria-disabled properties. Both of them come in as props, with disabled being an optional one. In my render method I do the following:

```
<div onClick={!this.props.Disabled ? this.props.Click : undefined} 
     aria-disabled={this.props.Disabled>My Div</div>
```

I use CSS to visualize the disabled state (opacity: 0.5, pointer-event: none blah blah). But I wonder if there's a better way to handle the actual onClick. Since it's a mandatory prop... so even when the item is disabled you still need to pass in an onClick to meet the condition. Is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: You could make the `Click` prop optional and give it a default value of `() => {}`.

Comment: @ZeroDarkThirty Learned something new  that `div` doesn't support `disabled`  Thanks 

Answer (score 43):

Set `pointer-events: none` for the `div[disabled]` in **CSS**,

**test.scss**

```
div[disabled]
{
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
```

The above code makes the contents of the div disabled, You can make the **div** disabled by adding the **disabled** attribute.

**Test.js**

```
<div disabled={this.state.disabled}>
  /* Contents */
</div>
```

Upon clicking the button you can change the state variable **disabled** as '**true**'.

```
handleClick = () =>{
    this.setState({
      disabled: true,
    });
  }
```

**Reference:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

Comment: you might want to write it as pointerEvents or it might throw an exception because the syntax slightly differs for react dom
div[disabled]
{
  pointerEvents: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

Answer (score 7):

**Why Answer Now?**
A developer with whom I work intends to use these answers as a reference. I believe a better answer could benefit him and others.

**What Does This Answer Provide?**
It provides *both* provide a solution that (a) is semantically accurate, (b) considers accessibility, and (c) uses existing answers; *and* review the existing answers.

**Any Additional Notes?**
How should a `<div>` behave differently when "disabled"? It is [a "generic container"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div)… nothing to disable. I use the behavior of existing answers:

- prevent mouse interaction with child elements
- identify the `<div>` as "disabled" to certain software

### Proposed Solution

***Note**: This solution uses [Functional Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components) syntax.*

```
div.is-disabled
{
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
```

```
/**
 * Render a button and an element whose content it "disables"
 *
 * NOTE: The "disabling" prevents user interaction with its children and to reduce the opacity of the entire element.
 *
 * @prop {Object} props
 * @prop {*} props.children - Any React-parseable children as the content
 * @function
 */
function MyComponent({ children }) {
  /** Whether content is disabled */
  let isDisabled = false;

  /**
   * When user clicks on element that should trigger "disabling" a div
   * @param {UIEvent} event
   * @function
   */
  const onClick (event) => {
    if (!isDisabled) {
      isDisabled = true;
    }
  }

  render (
    <>
      <div
        aria-disabled={isDisabled}
        className={(isDisabled) ? 'is-disabled' : ''}
      >
        {children}
      </div>
      <button onClick={onClick}>
        Disable Content
      </button>
    </>
  );
}
```

### Review of Existing Answers

#### [pramod-h-g's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55629927/11817077)

Great. This suggests a meaning for "disable a `<div>`", and a solution.

But, the markup concerns me.

- The `<div>` tag does not have a `disabled` attribute [^1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div#attributes) [^2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes).
- Using other elements' standard attribute on an element without such an attribute can confuse new developers.
- Custom attributes ([last I checked](https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/2271)) require a `data-` prefix.

#### [jpsimon's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51549897/11817077)

Answers question accurately—no faults.

*But, I think the `aria-disabled` attribute only "disables" the div for some user experiences. Visual browser users would not experience this `<div>` as being "disabled".*

#### [yts's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51549339/11817077)

I agree entirely.

*But, this solution does not "disable" a div. The original poster may not be asking the question appropriately, and I support you leading him toward a `<button>`.*

Answer (score 2):

I think you're intuition is right -- not ideal to be adding and removing event handlers all the time based on changing props. How about simply wrapping the function and returning as needed? As in the following E.g.

```
<div onClick={(e) => !this.props.Disabled && this.props.Click(e)}
  aria-disabled={this.props.Disabled}>
    My Div
</div>
```

Where the guard operator `&&` is shorthand for if logic.

Answer (score 0):

A `button` might be better suited for this. With a `button` element, the `onClick` will automatically not fire if the `disabled` value is true. So you could do:

```
<button onClick={this.props.Click} disabled={this.props.Disabled}>My button</button>
```

You also get the accessibility benefits of using a button over a div.

There is nothing wrong with the fact that the click prop is "extra" when the button is disabled, and I'd say it's better than changing the structure of the passed in props based on the disabled state.

Comment: @ZeroDarkThirty is there a reason for that? Buttons are generally better for accessibility purposes anyway and you seem to be concerned about aria